# Upload Buffer Directly to Google Cloud Storage

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-api, google-cloud-storage, google-api-client

I am fetching PDF document as `arraybuffer` from third party vendor. I want to upload that `arraybuffer` directly to Google Storage without creating a local copy of the file.

```
const axios = require('axios');
const google_storage = new Storage({ keyFilename: 'path_to_keyFilename' });

const upload_file = async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    let fetching_result = await axios({
      method: 'get',
      url: 'PDF_document_url',
      responseType: 'arraybuffer'
    });
    let upload_result = await google_storage.bucket('bucket_name').upload(fetching_result.data);
    return res.status(200).json(upload_result.data);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log('ERROR: ', error);
    return res.status(400).json(error);
  }
}
```

I am using the `@google-cloud/storage` package to do upload a file. But when I pass the `arraybuffer` to it, I got the following error:

> ERROR:  TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_VALUE]: The argument 'path' must be a string or Uint8Array without null bytes.
> Received <Buffer 25 50 44 46 2d 31 2e 35 0a 25 46 69 6c ...

I also tried to convert `arraybuffer` to `Uint8Array` and pass that, but then I receive the following error:

> ERROR:  TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_VALUE]: The argument 'path' must be a string or Uint8Array without null bytes.
> Received Uint8Array(116107) [ 37,  80,  68,  70,  45,  49,  46,  53,  10,  37, 216, 229 ...

Does anyone know what's happening here and how to solve this?

Comment: Could you provide a larger stack trace?

Comment: More importantly, please include the code you are using. E.g. is this attempting to use `Bucket.upload`, `File.save`, `File.createWriteStream` etc?

Comment: You are totally right. I updated my question. I tried to use `Bucket.upload()`.

Answer (score 4):

bucket.upload() expects a file name as first parameter, not the actual file you are trying to save.

File.createWriteStream() should work better:

```
const myData: Uint8Array = *something*;

const storage = new Storage();
const bucket = storage.bucket("myBucket");

const blob = bucket.file("myFile");
const blobStream = blob.createWriteStream({
    resumable: false,
});

blobStream.end(myData);
```

Comment: If you do that how do you set the metadata and access permissions on the file?